# Removing elements from a Vec based on some condition

Tags: rust

My code looks like this:

```
struct Bar {
    i: i32,
}

struct Foo {
    v: Vec<Bar>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn foo(&mut self) {
        self.v.drain(self.v.iter().filter(|b| b.i < 10));
    }
}
```

Note that `Bar` is not allowed to be copied or cloned.

I want to delete all `Bar`s that don't satisfy that condition. Initially I thought I could just iterate over them and call `remove` but I am not allowed to have two mutable borrows or one mutable borrow if there is an immutable borrow which makes total sense.

I guess the easiest thing would be to just `clone`, `filter` and `collect`, but I am not allowed to clone or copy.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you look at the interface of `Vec`, you will not find a method that erases some elements based on a predicate. Instead you will find [`retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain) which *keeps* the elements based on a predicate.

Of course, both are symmetric, it's just that `retain` is harder to find if you filter method names by "remove" or "erase" (it does contain "remove" in its description).

The example provided speaks for itself:

```
let mut vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
vec.retain(|&x| x % 2 == 0);
assert_eq!(vec, [2, 4]);
```

Comment: I make sense of the method's name in the following way: While "filter", confusingly, does not filter the elements that match the predicate, "retain" does retain the elements that match the predicate. I think this will be more intuitive for new programmers.

Comment: @mako: I also prefer `retain` for exactly this reason. I somehow have a hard time with booleans already, so if the semantics of which elements are kept/discarded are not clear, it's even harder on me.

Answer (score 17):

In nightly Rust, you can use [`Vec::drain_filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain_filter):

```
#![feature(drain_filter)]

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bar {
    i: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut bars = vec![Bar { i: 1 }, Bar { i: 10 }, Bar { i: 3 }, Bar { i: 100 }];
    bars.drain_filter(|b| b.i < 10);
    println!("{:?}", bars);
}
```

What's extra interesting about `drain_filter` is that you can get the rejected values as it returns an iterator of them:

```
let rejects: Vec<_> = bars.drain_filter(|b| b.i < 10).collect();
```

You can also choose to modify the value being iterated over:

```
bars.drain_filter(|b| {
    b.i -= 1;
    b.i < 10
});
```