# Rust "Types differ in mutability"

Tags: rust

I'm trying to remove an element from a vector if it existed in it:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn test(map: HashMap<String, Vec<String>>, department: String, employee: String) {
    let &mut list = map.get(&department).unwrap();
    let index = list.iter().position(|x| x == &employee);
    match index {
        Some(i) => {
            list.remove(i);
        },
        None => {
            println!("No records of {} in {}!", &employee, &department);
        },
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:4:9
  |
4 |     let &mut list = map.get(&department).unwrap();
  |         ^^^^^^^^^   ----------------------------- this expression has type `&std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>`
  |         |
  |         types differ in mutability
  |
  = note:      expected reference `&std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>`
          found mutable reference `&mut _`
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=40888df3bc4daf7f6979ef04b3f7533c)</sup>

I thought I understood what the error is saying (line 170's RHS returns a immutable reference to the vector), but I'm not so sure how to resolve it. If try something like this instead:

```
let mut list = map.get(&department).unwrap();
let index = list.iter().position(|x| x == &employee);
match index {
    Some(i) => {
        list.remove(i);
    },
    ...
}
```

I then get

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*list` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
 --> src/lib.rs:8:13
  |
4 |     let mut list = map.get(&department).unwrap();
  |         -------- help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>`
...
8 |             list.remove(i);
  |             ^^^^ `list` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5ca232b6741143a0b54bee49a59dbc94)</sup>

These errors seem kind of circular to me, which makes me feel I need to rethink my design. How would I go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) returns an immutable `Option<&V>` which won't let you call `.remove(i)`. Use [`get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_mut) to get a mutable `Option<&mut V>`. Calling it requires that the map itself be mutable, which is a sign that we're doing the right thing.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn test(map: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<String>>, department: String, employee: String) {
    //       ^^^^ 
    let list = map.get_mut(&department).unwrap();
    //             ^^^^^^^
    let index = list.iter().position(|x| x == &employee);
    match index {
        Some(i) => {
            list.remove(i);
        },
        None => {
            println!("No records of {} in {}!", &employee, &department);
        },
    }
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b1ef63266517d2b02ffcb3089a1ac634)</sup>

Comment: @cloudy_eclispse Note that you can use `Vec::retain` to simplify the `position`/`remove` dance. See [Removing elements from a Vec based on some condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37792471/3650362)

Comment: @trentcl : Looking at retain() closely now, and while that's fine for removing the element, Ideally I'd like to preserve the error message that I would display if the Result was none. Is there a neat way to do that?

Comment: @cloudy_eclispse Unfortunately not easily, no. You could use `drain_filter` on nightly (if it returns any items, they were removed; otherwise, print the message) but on stable this answer is probably your best option.